# Where does this mega-menu dropdown get its width from?

Tags: html, css

I can't figure this out for the life of me. When you..

[go here](http://geedmo.github.io/yamm/)

and click **'Accordian'** on the topbar, where does the dropdown menu get its width from? From the inspector, all I'm getting is a computed value which I'm not sure where is coming from. Could this width be coming from a JavaScript? It doesn't seem to be controlled by the children elements.

Cheers,

Comment: check css class `span6` of `<div id="accordion2" class="accordion  span6">`; change it to `span4` just to see if width changes

Comment: It gets this big width because you have a lot of text in your `accordion-inner` elements, that makes the parent controls as wide as the text.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From here:

```
 .yamm .dropdown.yamm-fullwidth .dropdown-menu {
   width: 100%;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
 }
 @media (max-width: 969px) {
   .yamm .dropdown.yamm-fullwidth .dropdown-menu {
     width: auto;
   }
   .yamm .yamm-content {
     padding-left: 0;
          padding-right: 0;
   }
   .yamm .dropdown-menu > li > ul {
     display: block;
   }
 }
```

At [this custom](http://geedmo.github.io/yamm/assets/css/yamm.css) file.

Answer (score -1):

From bootstrap ? It's a responsive template, so the width depend of your screen ;)

Go check the doc of bootstrap : [HERE](http://getbootstrap.com/)

I think there are min-width and max-width somewhere...

Comment: Remove `bootstrap.css`, CSS breaks and turns ugly, `<ul>` `width` continues big. Remove `Yamm.css`, still bootstrap, `width` reduces. Thus, this did not came from bootstrap responsiveness.

Answer (score -1):

Look like from here

```
.dropdown-menu {
    background-clip: padding-box;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    display: none;
    float: left;
    left: 0;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 2px 0 0;
    min-width: 160px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

go with firebug and add new line for test like

```
width:100px
```

or any amount and you will find the width shrink.

Comment: These attributes does not really change the width. Without out them it just breaks the CSS.

Comment: If you add things up, than it did't came form what was there but from what you just write. What you select came straight from bootstrap, when it is the custom `css` file which makes the width difference OP claimed.

Comment: Just checked the yamm css u provide, this line looking "suspicious" .yamm .dropdown.yamm-fullwidth .dropdown-menu {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

Answer (score -1):

It's using fluid widths as per the Bootstrap defaults.

By default everything `.row-fluid` will inherit a width of 100% (equivalent to `span12`).

The `accordion` class is assigned a `span6` so this will be 50% of the dropdown menu (minus padding/margins) so this creates the two columns in the dropdown and a left of auto on the dropdown menu ensures the megamenu dropdown only starts below adjacent to the parent menu item.